# Django translation of model plural when plural form equals singular form

Tags: django

How can you tell ugettext that the plural form is not the singular form even if they are equal in English?

```
class News(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('news')
        verbose_name_plural = _('news')
```

makemessages gives this:

```
#: models.py:134, models.:135
msgid "news"
msgstr "noticia"
```

Spliting this definition breaks the compilation with "duplicate message definition..."

Workarounds I found:

- Add a space at the end of the plural form (the one I am using)
- Write application texts in Esperanto? Just kidding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
from django.utils.translation import pgettext

class News(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = pgettext("news singular", "news")
        verbose_name_plural = pgettext("news plural", "news")
```

Comment: This is the contrary to what I am looking for. I want verbose_name_plural to have a different translation, no the same.

Comment: Hmm. Sorry, I mis-understood your question, which, the more I look at it, is an excellent question. I have updated my code example for you.

Comment: i changed your code to use pgettext_plural, but that did the trick. Thank you!